# FileNotFoundException using skmaps

Tags: java, android, android-studio, maps, skmaps

I'm creating an app using skobbler sdk.
When i try to show a map, the app crashes and the logcat show this error:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /res/xhdpi/icon_map_popup_navigate.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /res/xhdpi/icon_map_popup_arrow.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x4 in tid 4476 (GLThread 192609)
```

When i launch the demo app (by skobbler), everything works well.

P.S. the 2 images are present in my skmaps.zip.

Thank you!

Comment: Where are those images located? `/res` of your app or `/res` of the library?

Comment: Are located in a zip file in the assets folder of the app. At the first launch of application, I unzip this zip in the internal folder of the app (Data/data/). If i try to launch new File(PngPath).exist(), it returns true

Comment: @Anto: add these images in Drawable folder which is in `res`

Comment: @Anto What's `PngPath`? Address to assets or address to `res/` folder?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K i've already do this but not solve.

Comment: @Hi I'm frogatto pngPath is the addresso of res folder that i've unzipped. the path is this "/data/data/alo.com.geoapp/files/MYAPP/res/xhdpi/icon_map_popup_navigate.png"

Comment: @Anto Contents of `res` folder aren't get extracted into that folder.

Comment: @Hi I'm frogatto where i have to extact?

Comment: In the demo app there is some code inside the onCreate method (of the SplashActivity) - please include that code in your own app and let me know if it fixes the problem

Comment: @Ando I've copied the same code of demo app (splash and mapActivty

Answer (score 2):

> Are located in a zip file in the assets folder of the app.

No, it's not enough! You should extract that ZIP file in your `res/xhdpi` directory.

**Note:** Folders `drawable` / `mipmap`

Comment: I've try to launch skobbler demo application. And works fine. I've copied the same code but not work.

Comment: @Anto Did you extract that ZIP file in your `res` folder?

Comment: yes i have. The file are located in /data/data/alo.com.geoapp/files/MYAPP/res/xhdpi-hdpi etc

Comment: @Anto No, no. You shouldn't extract it in your device file system. If you're  using Android Studio, expand `res` folder and copy those images there. Clear ?

Comment: @Anto Copy those images in _all_ folders called `drawable-*`. Did you?

Comment: @Anto Is there any folders called `mipmap` ?

Comment: @Anto So, create a folder manually called `xhdpi` and copy them there.

Comment: @Anto In your app, do you use a library module?

Comment: i've added the image to the drawable folders in the Library Module but not solve.

Comment: @Anto That seems weird. Sorry I've no idea.